# How can I change default terminal away from LXTerminal?

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have Raspbian Lite installed and am trying to enable TrueColor, which defaults to LXTerminal.

This states that LXTerminal supports truecolor if I can run it with a flag https://gist.github.com/XVilka/8346728 `--enable-gtk3`

I was hoping just using `sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator` would work, but regardless of what I choose it still boots into LXTerminal.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be asked over at https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What if I changed the question to simply "How can I change the default terminal on a non GUI based OS?" This is something I've been searching for all day, and every answer involves some sort of GUI, and not a terminal based boot solution.